# Сравнить точно два массива по индексам и заменить значения Javascript

Tags: javascript, indexof

Как можно реализовать сравнение двух массивов равной длины n, так, чтобы элементы которые `array1[n] === array2[n]`, а не так чтобы, `array1 = ['a','b','','d']` и `array2 = ['a','','b','d']`, где у них индексы `[2] === [1]`.

Пробовал реализовать данный перебор элементов массивов через .filter(), но он возвращает не правильное соответствие значений.

```
let a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let b = ['a', 'b', 'd','c'];

let c = a.filter(n => b.indexOf(n) === -1);
console.log(c) // []
```

Но ведь это не так. `c !== d` и `d !== с`.

Задача. Заменить пробелы на 0, правильное соответствие индексов массива на 4, а не правильное на -1.

**Уточнение.** Чтобы два массива [...n] и [...m], где n - массив имеет правильные значения, а m - это ответы. Запушить в новый массив правильные значения (на своих позициях) равные 4 (за правильный), не правильные - отнять 1, а пропуск - ничего. Больше даже интересует какими методами надо такое реализовывать, includes & indexOf работают не так просто. filter() возвращает совпадения.

**Пример 1.** ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',...] и ['a', '', 'd', 'd', 'h', 'a',...] должно вернуть ответ: 4 + 0 -1 + +4 - 1 - 1 = 5

**Пример 2.**["a", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "c", "b", "d"] =  6

**Пример 3 .** ["a", "a", "c", "b"], ["a", "a", "b",  ""] =  7

Comment: Написать цикл, очевидно

Comment: Пока не очень понятно, добавьте несколько входных и выходных примеров

Comment: `let c = a.filter((n, i) => b[i] === n);` это вы хотите что-ли сделать? вернет ['a', 'b']

Comment: Добавил уточнение.

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Приведите примеры входных данных и соответствующих результатов.

Comment: Добавлены примеры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let c = a.filter(n => b.indexOf(n) === -1);` — indexOf вообще проверяет номер элемента `n` в массиве `b` и возвращает -1 только если его там нет. Соответственно, в результате фильтрации останутся только те элементы `a` которых нет в массиве `b`.

Но для решения задачи не нужно никаких хитрых переборов. Нужна сумма - считайте сумму:

```js
let real_answers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
let user_answers = ['a', '', 'd', 'd', 'h', 'a'];

let total_points = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < real_answers.length; i++) {
  if (user_answers[i] === "") continue; // +0 ?! Строка пустая - ничего не делать.
  
  total_points += (user_answers[i] === real_answers[i]) ? 4 : -1; 
               //  Совпадают ? будет +4 : иначе -1
}

console.log(total_points);
```

Если хочется использовать методы массива, здесь вместо filter подходит [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let real_answers = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
let user_answers = ['a', '', 'd', 'd', 'h', 'a'];

let points = user_answers.reduce(function(total, answer, index) {
  total += !answer ? 0 : answer === real_answers[index] ? 4 : -1;
  //    Нет ответа ? 0 : совпадают ? 4 : иначе -1
  return total;
}, 0);

// .reduce((sum, e, i) => sum + ( !e ? 0 : e === real_answers[i] ? 4 : -1 ), 0);

console.log(points);
```

Comment: Все верно поняли, спасибо. Про 'continue' вообще не догадался. Почему-то думал существует метод который перебирает значения.

Comment: Спасибо за другой пример реализации данной задачи. reduce() тоже интересно было увидеть.